# Add inline CSS to login page with wp_add_inline_style

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

Trying to add inline style with `wp_add_inline_style` to **login** page by targeting login-css style sheet..

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'bt_css_login', 1009 );
/**
 * Enqueue Login CSS
 *
 * @since 1.0
 */

function bt_css_login() {

    $handle  = 'login';
    $css = '';
    $css .= '

        .hello {
            color:red;
        }';

    if ( $css ) {
        wp_add_inline_style( $handle, $css );
    }
}
```

Style sheet does not appear.

Comment: It works for me. I just checked it through the Code Snippets plugin.

Comment: Yes it does work - thanks, I had an issue in my original code.